# Display specific eloquent query in nova resource index view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I want to display the following eloquent in index view for nova resource

```
Post::where('frontpage', true)->get()
```

And perform Post model CRUD operations, How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try to create a [lense](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/lenses/defining-lenses.html) to customize the underlying eloquent query?

Comment: no, but i'll consider that, thanx for the hint ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply override `indexQuery` of your Nova resource, [Reference](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/authorization.html#index-filtering)

```
/**
 * Build an "index" query for the given resource.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('frontpage', true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Nova utilizes the concept of [lenses](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/lenses/defining-lenses.html) to do this.

Create a new lens from the command line:

```
php artisan nova:lens IsFrontpage
```

Modify the `query()` method in `app/Nova/Lenses/IsFrontpage.php`:

```php
public static function query(LensRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $request->withOrdering($request->withFilters(
        $query->where('frontpage', '=', true)
    ));
}
```

Attach the lens to a resource:

```php
public function lenses(Request $request)
{
    return [
        new IsFrontpage()
    ];
}
```

Access the lens in the Nova admin panel: `/nova/resources/posts/lens/is-frontpage`

Take a closer look at the [Nova documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/lenses/defining-lenses.html) to also customize the URL slug (see `uriKey()`) and the columns (see `fields()`).